# NodeJS - all short(abbreviated) word to full word feature module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I want to convert some abbreviated word to full word of string sentence make simple and clear sentence in NodeJS

**For Example**

```
i'm => I am
i've => I have
w'ill => we will
lets => Let us
it's => It is
```

I have installed `gingerbread` and using this module it is checking grammar mistake only. Is any module available for processing text like this?

Comment: @JordiFlores, please understand my question, if you not understand properly let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short forms in English is called **contractions**.
You can use **contractions** npm module for you purposes `npm install contractions`

It's quite simple to use. Quick example:

```
let contractions = require('contractions');

console.log(contractions.expand("I don't know who ya'll are."));
// Outputs: I do not know who you all are. 

console.log(contractions.contract("You all will have not seen this."));
// Outputs: Y'all'll'ven't seen this.
```

You can find more info here https://www.npmjs.com/package/contractions

Comment: Thanks very much.. but I am not sure this module follow nature of English grammar...

Answer (score 1):

There's no such package for JS, however, there could be fast and hard rules for replacing *contractions*:

```
var replacements = {
    "'m":  " am",
    "'ll": " will",
    "'re": " are",
    "n't": " not",
    "'ve": " have",
}
```

I use it from time to time.

But the real problem is to distinguish sentences that contain "he could", "he would", "he had" - no way simple algorithm can tell the difference in "he'd". This would require some serious pattern recognition, which is accomplished only through machine learning.

This is, I suppose, the reason why such package is a no-go.

---

**Update:**

As it turns out, I was **wrong** about such package existence(from *@itereshchenkov* answer), but **right** about nature of meaningful contractions. Simple package that uses dictionary of replacements (no matter how big it is) can't correctly decide which full form is used without understanding context.

Answer (score 0):

```
var replacements = {
  "I'm": "I am",
  "we'll": "we will"
}

var sentence = "I'm sure we'll have a good time."

for (var k in replacements) {
  sentence = sentence.replace(k, replacements[k])
}

console.log(sentence)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am asking about modules which facilitate this conversion for all short words.